# Unravel JSON expression

Tags: json, webserver

I have this JSON expression

```json
{
  "uid":false,
  "token":null,
  "ma":null,
  "question":[
    {
      "questionId":47599,
      "answerId":190054,
      "answer":1
    }
  ],
  "iframe":true,
  "ref":"<SOMEREFERRER>",
  "ts":1711214476
}
```

that a webclient (in this case, Google Chrome and Firefox on iOS) wants to send to a webserver. It is a reply on a survey form another server (SOMEREFERRER) has sent. I am rather unfamiliar with JSON and wondering what this string is exactly doing when posted to the target server.

I have found that the survey server is accepting this string multiple times and counts it as a "vote". This is not supposed to happen.

Comment: JSON itself doesn't do anything. It's just data. The server decides what to do with the data after it has received it. Your guess is as good as anyone else's.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.